# How Save ListBox as txt

Tags: vb.net

**I'm trying to create a save button that saves some integers from a listbox.**

I'm not exactly sure how to write to the file. The program already write the correct number of items in the list, just not what content in the listbox.

I've gotten the listbox to write to a .txt file. So far when I write to the file all I get is *System.Windows.Forms.ListBox, Items.Count: 3, Items[0]: 10*

```
    Dim filename As String
    Dim tempSave As StreamWriter

    filename = InputBox("Please enter a filename to save this data")
    Try
        tempSave = File.CreateText(filename)

        For i As Integer = 0 To priceList.Items.Count - 1
            tempSave.WriteLine(priceList)

        Next
        tempSave.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("That file cannot be created.")

    End Try
```

I should see the integers I enter from the listbox that the user enters.

Comment: `tempSave.WriteLine(priceList)`  You should really look at that line hard.  Hint: you are ignoring your loop.

Comment: @LarsTech the loop is not even necessary. : `tempSave.Write(String.Join(vbNewLine, ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String)).Trim)` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
       For i As Integer = 0 To priceList.Items.Count - 1
        tempSave.WriteLine(priceList.Items(i).ToString)
       Next
```

Comment: I was able to use this method correctly! Thank you so much, I actually did               *tempSave.WriteLine(priceList.Items(i))*
which saved me a bit of space.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as @nbk but a bit simpler.

```
For Each line In ListBox1.Items
    tempSave.WriteLine(line.ToString)
Next
```

Comment: Or even this is shorter `tempSave.Write(String.Join(vbNewLine, ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String)).Trim)`.